# Creating property-less nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a schema like `(:A)-[:TYPE_1]-(:B)-[:TYPE_2]-(:A)`. I need to link `[:TYPE_1]` and `[:TYPE_2]`  Relationships to certain other Nodes (Say, types C,D,E etc.). I had to create some Nodes without any properties, like `(:A)-[:TYPE_1]-(:Action)--(:B)--(:Action)-[:TYPE_2]-(:A)`. The only purpose of the `(:Action)` Nodes is to enable me to link the action to some other Nodes (because I can't link a relationship to a Node). Thus, there are no properties associated with them. Since I changed my schema, I am finding that `MERGE` queries have slowed down incredibly. Obviously, I can't index the `(:Action)` Nodes, but all other Indexes are in place. What could be going wrong?

Edit:
My logic is that 1) There are multiple csv files 2) Each row in each file provides one `(a1:A)-[:TYPE_1]-(type_1:Action)--(b:B)--(type_2:Action)-[:TYPE_2]-(a2:A)` pattern. 3) Two different files may provide the same `a1`,`a2` and `b` entities. 4) However, if the file pertains to `a1`, it will give qualifiers for `type_1` and if the file pertains to `a2`, it will give qualifiers for `type_2`. 5) Hence, I do an `OPTIONAL MATCH` to see if the pattern exists. 6) If it doesn't, I create the pattern, qualifying either `type_1`, or `type_2` based on a parameter in the row called `qualifier`, which can be `type_1` or `type_2`. 7) If it does, then I just qualify the `type_1` or `type_2` as the case may be.

```
statement = """
              MERGE (file:File {id:$file})
              WITH file
              UNWIND $rows as row
              MERGE (a1:A {id:row.a1})
              ON CREATE
              SET a1.name=row.a1_name
              MERGE (a2:A {id:row.a2})
              ON CREATE
              SET a2.name=row.a2_name
              MERGE (b:B {id:row.b})
              ON CREATE
              SET b.name = row.b_name, 
              
          MERGE (c:C {id:row.c})

          MERGE (d:D {id:row.d})

          MERGE (e:E {id:row.e})

          MERGE (b)-[:FROM_FILE]->(file)


          WITH b,c,d,e,a1,a2,row
          OPTIONAL MATCH (a1)-[:TYPE_1]->(type_1:Action)-[:INITIATED]->(b)<-[:INITIATED]-(type_2:Action)<-[:TYPE_2]-(a2)
          WITH a1,b,a2,row,c,d,e,type_1,type_2
          CALL apoc.do.when(type_1 is null,
                            "WITH a1,b,a2,row,c,d,e
                                CALL apoc.do.when(row.qualifier = 'type1',
                                                'CREATE (type_1:Action)
                                                CREATE (type_2:Action)
                                                MERGE (a1)-[:TYPE_1 ]->(type_1)-[:INITIATED]->(b)<-[:INITIATED]-(type_2)<-[:TYPE_2 ]-(a2)
                                                MERGE (type_1)-[:WITH_C]->(c)
                                                MERGE (type_1)-[:WITH_D]->(d)
                                                MERGE (type_1)-[:WITH_E]->(e)',
                                                'CREATE (type_1:Action)
                                                CREATE (type_2:Action)
                                                MERGE (a1)-[:TYPE_1]->(type_1)-[:INITIATED]->(b)<-[:INITIATED]-(type_2)<-[:TYPE_2 ]-(a2)
                                                MERGE (type_2)-[:WITH_C]->(c)
                                                MERGE (type_2)-[:WITH_D]->(d)
                                                MERGE (type_2)-[:WITH_E]->(e)',
                                                {row:row,a1:a1,a2:a2,b:b,c:c,d:d,e:e})
                                YIELD value
                                RETURN value",

                            "
                            WITH row,c,d,e,type_1,type_2
                                CALL apoc.do.when(row.qualifier = 'type1',
                                                'MERGE (type_1)-[:WITH_C]->(c)
                                                 MERGE (type_1)-[:WITH_D]->(d)
                                                 MERGE (type_1)-[:WITH_E]->(e)',
                                                'MERGE (type_2)-[:WITH_C]->(c)
                                                 MERGE (type_2)-[:WITH_D]->(d)
                                                 MERGE (type_2)-[:WITH_E]->(e)',
                                                 {row:row,type_1:type_1,type_2:type_2,c:c,d:d,e:e})
                            YIELD value
                            RETURN value",
                            {row:row,a1:a1,a2:a2,b:b,c:c,d:d,e:e,type_1:type_1,type_2:type_2})
                YIELD value
                


          RETURN count(*) as count
            
            """
params = []
for row in df.itertuples():
    params_dict = {'a1': row[1], 'a1_name': row[-3],'a2':row[2],'a2_name':row[-4],'b_name':row[3],'b':row[-2],'c':int(row[6]),'d':row[7],'e':row[5],'qualifier':row[-1]}
    params.append(params_dict)
    if row[0] % 5000 == 0:
        graph.run(statement, parameters = {"rows" : params,'file':file})
        params = []
graph.run(statement, parameters = {"rows" : params,'file':file})
```

Comment: It would help if you share the MERGE queries that are slow

Comment: Sorry @Graphileon, I should have done it in the first place. Have edited the original question.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly what the issue is but I do notice that you use `MERGE` a bit more than you actually need to. In your `apoc.do.when` call you call

```
MERGE (a1)-[:TYPE_1 ]->(type_1)-[:INITIATED]->(b)<-[:INITIATED]-(type_2)<-[:TYPE_2 ]-(a2)
```

even though you know that you just created `type_1` and `type_2` so none of the relationships exist. If you change that to a `CREATE` you should see a speedup. The same logic applies to the other `MERGE` calls in that statement.

Comment: Yes Simon. I’d figured that out. Thanks for pointing. I think the bottleneck is when the pattern is existing (the last part of the query).

Comment: Have you tried calling PROFILE on it? You could also add some timing in the python code to see if it's particular parts of the CSV file that is taking a long time or if every call to the database is equally slow.

Comment: I haven’t really done either. These are good suggestions. Thanks again.